# Telegram Bot in ASP.Net Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telegram, telegram-bot

I have this "Net Core Console App" code for Telegram Bot

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly TelegramBotClient bot = new TelegramBotClient(MyToken);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bot.OnMessage += tgramBotTestMSG;
        bot.StartReceiving();
        Console.ReadLine();
        bot.StopReceiving();
    }

    private static void tgramBotTestMSG(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text)
            PrepareQuestionnaires(e);
    }

    public static void PrepareQuestionnaires(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Text.ToLower() == "hi")
            bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "hello");
    }
}
```

Is it possible that I would write this code in a class file in my ASP.net Web Forms Project and run this class on Page Load? If so, how can I do that?
And if not, what are other ways to integrate my Telegram bot and most importantly RECEIVE and SEND messages on my Bot using ASP.net Web forms?

Comment: Have you tried moving this code "as is" to your web application? It is not working there?

Comment: Roman Kalinchuk yes I did that but I had to add "string[] args" in my page load and consequently the strings that I've saved in my web form would not save a value

Comment: "I had to add "string[] args" in my page load"...why? You didn't need to do that.

Comment: Anyway this won't fit well into a web application directly. The C# code in a request only runs for the short amount of time while the page is being loaded. As soon as the HTML data is returned to the browser, the C# stops executing until another request is made by the browser. Then it starts again from the beginning (as if it never ran before). Web apps are stateless. Therefore you can't use the page_load event to listen for messages from the bot.

Comment: I suggest you could convert the listening part of this app into a Windows Service which can run constantly in the background in your server. It can log any received messages into a database table (or other storage), so that the web application can read the latest messages whenever the relevant page is loaded. You could then maybe enhance that with a queue system and maybe use SignalR to send/receive messages to/from the browser to asp.net in real-time.

Comment: Or instead of the windows service you could see if you could integrate something like Hangfire to do the long-running listening process in the background of your asp.net app. Not sure how well it integrates with WebForms (as opposed to MVC) though, I don't have experience of that.

Comment: ADyson - That helped a lot! Thank you so much. I'll try doing what you recommended. It is the first time me doing so and that'll help me for later. Appreciated!